# Swiffy Object Alignment in Table

Tags: javascript, css, html, flash

I have used swiffy to convert my swf to HTML5. I use aspx, its a small size banner which I want to appear on the left sidebar. The whole left side uses table for data. I want the object to appear in a table column. Currently it didn't appear in table column. The following was old code for flash.

```
<td height="244"><object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,29,0" width="158" height="244">
<param name="movie" value="images/image_left.swf">
<param name="quality" value="high">
<embed src="images/image_left.swf" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="158" height="244"></embed></object>
```

Following is HTML5 script, which I want to appear at the same location.

```
<td height="244">
    <script>var stage = new swiffy.Stage(document.body, swiffyobject);</script>
    <script>stage.start();</script>
</td>
```

Please provide me help, I need it badly.

Comment: Hi Tahir, can you please show real time problem or images/screen shot or the code where exactly you facing problem because with a bit of code you provided i think me/some one is not able to help you and you are asking question about Flash which is bit difficult in this situation.

Comment: Thanks Happy singh, I have edited my question please have a look.

Comment: HI Tahir, i read about swiffy on this link - http://www.google.com/doubleclick/studio/swiffy/faq.html The "Export to HTML5" option is not present in the Commands menu.

The Swiffy Extension will only be installed for the language of the Extension Manager. If the language of the Extension Manager is different to the language of Flash Professional, then the Swiffy Extension will not be visible. To make it available in Flash, open the Extension Manager from inside Flash Professional (Help > Manage Extensions...).
 You can check the setting you have or browser compatiblity etc.

Comment: It does work, all of the transitions are also applied, but the main point is placement within the TD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, put the id="name_for_id" in the td tag.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
<td height="244" id="name_for_id">
    <script>var stage = new swiffy.Stage(document.getElementById("name_for_id"), swiffyobject);</script>
    <script>stage.start();</script>
</td>
```